# Regexpr in python

Tags: python, regex

```
for printJobString in logfile:
    userRegex = re.search('(\suser:\s)(.+?)(\sprinter:\s)', printJobString)
    if userRegex:
        userString = userRegex.group(2)
        pagesInt = int(re.search('(\spages:\s)(.+?)(\scode:\s)', printJobString).group(2))
```

above is my code, when I run this program in the module I end up getting,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brandon\Desktop\project3\project3\pages.py", line 45, in <module>
    log2hist("log")  # version 2.
  File "C:\Users\brandon\Desktop\project3\project3\pages.py", line 29, in log2hist
    pagesInt = int(re.search('(\spages:\s)(.+?)(\scode:\s)', printJobString).group(2))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I know this error means the search is returning `None` but I'm not sure how to handle this case. Any help would be appreciated, very new to python and still learning the basics.

I am writing a program that should print out the number of pages a user has. 
**180.186.109.129 code: k n h user: luis printer: core 2 pages: 32** 
is a target string, my python file is trying to create a data file that has one line for each user and contains the total number of pages printed

Comment: This is a regex issue, not a Python issue. You should debug your regex at http://regexr.com/ or post a question with your regex pattern and an example target string.

Comment: edited to try to be more clear in my goal @ap

Comment: @ap I am trying to use regexr.com but I think the format I am using to search through the file for "user:" "printer:" is correct, I'm unsure what I am doing wrong here, to my knowledge it is scanning for those words and ignoring the white spaces. My thought process is clearly wrong as it is not doing what I believe it should be doing

Comment: You're not ignoring white spaces, you're matching them. If there's no space in front of 'user:' for instance, it won't match. You should really close this question and make a new one, and tag it with 'regex'.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it happens is because your regexp does not find anything and returns None

```
re.search('(\spages:\s)(.+?)(\scode:\s)') returns None
```

use an if statement to test if it's not None before you try to group

```
for printJobString in logfile:
    userRegex = re.search('(\suser:\s)(.+?)(\sprinter:\s)', printJobString)
    if userRegex:
        userString = userRegex.group(2)
        pagesInt = re.search('(\spages:\s)(.+?)(\scode:\s)', printJobString)

        if pagesInt:
           pagesInt = int(pageInts.group(2))
```

Comment: I added that to my code but I get the error **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brandon\Desktop\project3\project3\pages.py", line 48, in <module>
    log2hist("log")  # version 2.
  File "C:\Users\brandon\Desktop\project3\project3\pages.py", line 30, in log2hist
    if pageInt:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pageInt' referenced before assignment** @danidee

Comment: @bkennedy because your `if userRegex` doesn't eval to true, your `pagesInt` never gets assigned; then, when you check it in the next `if` it's not there.